# Arraylist in textboxfor type of Date in table Partial view mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, datetime, arraylist

Hello I have a very Strange Problem
I have arraylist  contains id,datetime and boolen(Chechbox)
when it binds in the table All Values correctly The issue that textboxfor(Type = Date) only first Row in Table displays wrong Values and when i inspected binded Values were right in inspect all other rows are displaying correctly i can't catch the issue 
[image]
[image]

all i want is to make first (All rows) Binds correctly 
anyone knows why this happen or have any recommendation to solve this issue

```
<tbody id="employeeScheduleList">

    @try
    {
        if (Model != null && Model.R != null && Model.R.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var file in Model.R)

            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(x => file.FileName, file.FileName, new { id = "FileID" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => file.FileIDValue, new { @class = "form-control hidden  EMPF" })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => file.FileIDValue)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => file.FileName)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => file.ReceivingDateValue, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control ReceivingDate ", type = "Date", id = "ReceivingDate_" })
                            @if (file.ReceivingDateValue != null)
                            {
                                <script>
                                var t = document.getElementById("ReceivingDate_");
                                  t.value = '@file.ReceivingDateValue.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")';
                                </script>
                            }
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => file.ReceivingDateValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => file.ExpiryDateValue, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control ExpiryDate ", type = "Date", id = "ExpiryDate_" })
                            @if (file.ExpiryDateValue != null)
                            {
                                <script>
                                   var t = document.getElementById("ExpiryDate_");
                                   t.value = '@file.ExpiryDateValue.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")';
                                </script>
                            }
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => file.ExpiryDateValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => file.ReturnedDateValue, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control ReturnedDate ", type = "Date", id = "ReturnedDate_" })
                            @if (file.ReturnedDateValue != null)
                            {
                                <script>
                                  var t = document.getElementById("ReturnedDate_");
                                  t.value = '@file.ReturnedDateValue.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")';
                                </script>
                            }
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReturnedDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => file.PermanentReturnDateValue, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control PermanentReturnDate ", type = "Date", id = "PermanentReturnDate_" })
                            @if (file.PermanentReturnDateValue != null)
                            {
                            <script>
                                     var t = document.getElementById("PermanentReturnDate_" );
                                    t.value = '@file.PermanentReturnDateValue.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")';
                            </script>
                            }
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => file.PermanentReturnDateValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span class="form-control">
                                @if (file.IsReceivedValue == true)
                                {
                                    <label class="checkbox checkbox-custom-alt checkbox-custom-sm m-0">
                                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="selectMe IsReceived">
                                        <i></i>
                                    </label>

                                    @*@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.R[i].IsReceivedValue.HasValue, new { @class = "IsReceived", id = "Received_" + Model.R[i].FileIDValue, @checked = "checked" })*@
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <label class="checkbox checkbox-custom-alt checkbox-custom-sm m-0">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="selectMe IsReceived">
                                        <i></i>
                                    </label>

                                    @*@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.R[i].IsReceivedValue.HasValue, new { @class = "IsReceived", id = "Received_" + Model.R[i].FileIDValue, value = "0" })*@
                                }


                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        <script>
    alert('@ex.Message');
console.log(ex);
        </script>
    }

</tbody>
```

Comment: Hi, can you show some relevant code as well?

Comment: @shyamaa adel you want to add checkbox from the list? Can you please share the code so I can take a look and help you to resolve the issue..

Comment: @stefan i had update the post and add table code

Comment: @prince Chopra no i don't want to add checkbox from the list
i want data in first row binds correct as it comes from the list i had update the post and add table cod